# How do I remove a Policy (ExtensionInstallSources) from Google Chrome?

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome

I have Google Chrome 79.0 and Ubuntu 18.04. When I go to `chrome://settings/` it shows

> Your browser is managed by your organization

When I go to `chrome://policy/` it shows

> ExtensionInstallSources: https://lastpass.com/*,https://*.lastpass.com/*,https://d1jxck0p3rkj0.cloudfront.net/lastpass/*

I once tried lastpass, but I uninstalled it. I don't find any trace of it, except for this.

I would like to remove that. My private browser should not be managed by an organization. How do I do that?